# Node & Redis: Redis Clients

Tags: javascript, performance, api, node.js, redis

Assume you have **multiple** db's in Redis you would like to insert and/or remove data from. You have a flow like;

- Insert data to **DB #1**
- After the first insertion's **callback** do some stuff and insert data to **DB #2**
- After the second insertion's **callback** do some stuff again and finally insert data to **DB #3**

I use one variable called **redisClient** that is basically created as;

```
redisClient = redis.createClient();
```

And while selecting a new DB, I use **select** command with the extra pre-caution callback, so my select command is like;

```
redisClient.select(1, function(err) {
  //Some programming logic (Insertion, deletion and stuff)
  redisClient.select(2, function(err) {
    //Do some additional programming logic (Insertion, deletion and stuff)
  }
});
```

However things get constantly mix. I would like to note that the redisClient variable has been assigned only once and later on used throughout the entire application. Now I was wondering, how reasonable would it be to use **seperate redisClients for each DB** I have in Redis. So it would be like;

```
redisClientForDB1 = redis.createClient();
redisClientForDB2 = redis.createClient();
redisClientForDB3 = redis.createClient();
```

I was wondering would it be reasonable, or would it be a right way for an application that will receive **4K requests per sec** and about to go to the production mode. What **issues** this model might face?

Answer (score 16):

Just as [Carl Zulauf said](/questions/13971145/node-redis-redis-clients/14127737#14006599), it's best to open 3 different connections (one per DB):

```
redisClient = {
  DB1: redis.createClient(),
  DB2: redis.createClient(),
  DB3: redis.createClient()
};
```

It's best to open all connections once during the initialization of your server:

```
async.parallel([
  DB1.select.bind(DB1, 1),
  DB2.select.bind(DB2, 2),
  DB3.select.bind(DB3, 3)
], next);
```

So, after you created `redisClient` object and initialized it you can use it to handle all your redis operations.

If you'll use redis this way node will open 3 (and only 3) connections per node process.

---

**N.B.** It's also a good idea to put it all into one node module:

```
module.exports = {
  DB1: redis.createClient(),
  DB2: redis.createClient(),
  DB3: redis.createClient(),
  init: function(next) {
    var select = redis.RedisClient.prototype.select;
    require('async').parallel([
      select.bind(this.DB1, 1),
      select.bind(this.DB2, 2),
      select.bind(this.DB3, 3)
    ], next);
  }
};
```

Then you'll be able to initialize all your redis connections by calling `init` function once (because node caching `require` calls):

```
require('./lib/my_redis').init(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  server.listen();
});
```

Then when `require('./lib/my_redis').DB1.set('key','val')` will be called in any of your modules `DB1` will be already initialized.

Answer (score 11):

Using 3 connections for 3 different databases is the correct approach. There is overhead for having additional connections open, but that overhead is very small.

With something like hundreds of open connections the overhead would start to be a problem. I'm not sure how many instances of your app you will run but guessing at just 3 connections per process you won't get anywhere near problematic numbers.

Comment: Yep! Using separate clients for each connection is the way to go :)

Answer (score 8):

If Google brought you here, do yourself a favour: don't use multiple DB support. Use namespaced keys or multiple redis instances.

I say this after having struggled with multiple DB support in an async environment myself. At wits end, I visited #redis on Freenode and was referred to the following statement by Redis' author, Salvatore Sanfilippo:

> I consider Redis multiple database errors my worst decision in Redis
>   design at all...  I hope that
>   at some point we can drop the multiple DBs support at all, but I think
>   it is probably too late as there is a number of people relying on this
>   feature for their work.
>
> https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redis-db/vS5wX8X4Cjg/8ounBXitG4sJ

You really want to think twice before relying on *the* feature the author regrets the most.

Comment: What are the practical problems with using this feature?

Comment: You have to start your entire service as a callback to the DB select command. It's awkward to have main be a configuration callback, particularly when multiple configuration elements work this way. For one thing, it makes it impossible to fail fast on configuration errors.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having 3 different connections for 3 different DBs you can as well use `MULTI/EXEC` block for this:

```
redisClient.multi().select(1).set("my_key_in_db_1","myval").exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using one instance for each database is the correct approach. But if you need to reuse or throttle expensive resources such as database connections, then a database connection pool could be a good choice. Let's say we choose [generic-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) (a generic pooling solution for node.js), you can code like this:

```
// Step 1 - Create pool using a factory object
var mysql= require('mysql'),
    generic_pool = require('generic-pool');

var pool = generic_pool.Pool({
    name: 'mysql pool 1',
    min: 1,
    max: 50,
    idleTimeoutMillis : 30000,
    create   : function(callback) {
        var Client = mysql.Client;
        var c = new Client();
        c.user     = 'myusername';
        c.password = 'mypassword';
        c.database = 'mydb';
        c.connect();

        callback(null, c);
    },
    destroy  : function(client) { client.end(); }
});

// Step 2 - Use the pool in your code to acquire/release resources
pool.acquire(function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
        return res.end("CONNECTION error: " + err);
    }
    client.query("select * from foo", [], function() {
        // return object back to pool
        pool.release(client);
    });
});
```

Comment: And you can do pooling using `mysql` module itself: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#pooling-connections